# How do I assign a formula to a variab

Tags: assignment

I want to compute equations and assign them to variable.  This is a wxMaxima program that calculated symbolic PID gains for an integrating first order system

```
remvalue(all)$                      /* Undefine                         */
Gp: K*%alpha/(s*(s+%alpha));        /* System transfer function         */
Gc: Ki/s+Kp+Kd*s;                   /* Simple PID controller            */
CLTF: ratsimp(Gc*Gp/(1+Gc*Gp));     /* Closed loop transfer function    */
CE: expand(denom(ratsimp(CLTF)));   /* Characteristic equation          */
DIFCE: expand(CE-(s+%lambda)^3);
Ki: solve(coeff(DIFCE,s,0),Ki);
Kp: solve(coeff(DIFCE,s,1),Kp);
Kd: solve(coeff(DIFCE,s,2),Kd);
grind(Ki,Kp,Kd);
```

The grind outputs text that I can paste here

```
[Ki = %lambda^3/(%alpha*K)]$
    [Kp = 3*%lambda^2/(%alpha*K)]$
[Kd = (3*%lambda-%alpha)/(%alpha*K)]$
```

Notice that Ki, Kp and Kd represent equations.  This is what I want because I can change the values and compute new gains.

This is my Mathematica equivelent

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Subscript[G, p][s] = (K*\[Alpha])/(s*(s + \[Alpha]))
Subscript[G, c][s] = Ki/s + Kp + Kd*s
T[s] = Subscript[G, c][s]*
   Subscript[G, p][s]/(1 + Subscript[G, c][s]*Subscript[G, p][s]) // 
  Simplify
Solve[{CoefficientList[Denominator[T[s]], s] == 
   CoefficientList[(s + \[Lambda])^3, s]}, {Ki, Kp, Kd}]
```

This looks ugly because I haven't found the Mathematica version of grind() yet.
Notice that the results are in the form Ki->Lamba^3/(K*Alpha).  The -> is not an assignment so I can't treat Ki as a formula.

```
             3                    2
    \[Lambda]          3 \[Lambda]         -\[Alpha] + 3 \[Lambda]
{{Ki -> ---, Kp -> ----, Kd -> --------}}
    K \[Alpha]        K \[Alpha]           K \[Alpha]
```

How do I assign Lambda^3/(K*Alpha) using equations instead of by hand?
I give up.  formatting what get much better.

Edit
    Solve[{CoefficientList[Denominator[T[s]], s] == 
       CoefficientList[(s + [Lambda])^3, s]}, {Ki, Kp, Kd}] /. Rule-> Equal

Does not work.  When I type Ki for I get Ki in return and not the equal for Ki.

This looks like it works

s = Solve[{CoefficientList[Denominator[T[s]], s] == 
    CoefficientList[(s + [Lambda])^3, s]}, {Ki, Kp, Kd}]
{{Ki, Kp, Kd}} = { Ki, Kp, Kd } /. s

Comment: Try like this `{{x -> -a - Sqrt[-1 + a^2]}, {x -> -a + Sqrt[-1 + a^2]}} /. Rule -> Equal`

Comment: I need to use /. Rule -> Equal

Comment: You should do something like Ki1=Ki/.s Then Ki1 will be the solution. Check Menu/Help/Documentation Center/Solve

Comment: I think it is the off-topic case, since the problem is that the OP is unaware of the basic documentation.